# I cannot create a good log file

Tags: ftp

Found the Solution !!!!

After a gob of Googling, I found this in a forum from a person asking " How to: Add or display today’s date from a shell script"

This is what I did

I added the following to the beginning of my ftp script

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=$(date)
HOST=$(hostname)
echo "--------------------------------------------"
echo "This script was run: $TODAY ON HOST:$HOST "
echo "--------------------------------------------"
# below is original code minus the #!/bin/sh
#
cd /folder where csv files are/
ftp -v -i -n 111.222.333.444 <<EOF
user mainuser dbuser
mput phas*.csv
bye
EOF
```

Now my log, on each cron event of the ftp'ing, show:

---

### This script was run: Tue Nov 12 11:16:02 EST 2013 ON MyServer's HostName>

On the crontab, I changed the entry for logging to include 2 >> so the log is appended and not re-written:

16 11 * * * /srv/phonedialer_tmp/ftp-date.sh **&>>** /srv/phonedialer_tmp/ftp-date.log

I found a way to create a log file of daily ftp's by searching here:

./ftp_csv.sh   2>&1 > ftp_csv.log

I works great in that is records each time the cronjob runs.   However, what I cannot find is a way to insert the date/time of each event.  As you can see below, it records the transferring of the files.
is there a way I can somehow add the date/timestamp to the beginning or end of each recorded event within the log file?

```
[stevek@localhost phonedialer_tmp]$ cat ftp_csv.log
Connected to 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4).
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required for mainuser.
230 User mainuser logged in.
221 
Connected to 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4).
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required for mainuser.
230 User mainuser logged in.
221 
Connected to 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4).
220 Microsoft FTP Service
331 Password required for mainuser.
230 User mainuser logged in.
221                                  ETC
```

Thanks so much for any information

Comment: @admdrew  I noticed you had created an "edit" but I cannot find any difference in what I had typed.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I just added formatting for your console output for readability; notice how it's in a grey block and has a different font.

Comment: That does look very nice.  Is this something I can do when I am creating the question?

Comment: Yes! Check out http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @admdrew  thanks for the formatting tips.  Do you have any ideas on the actual question I posted?